# How to select a specific node in a TreeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp

I built a treeviewer for a specific project, but now I need to select a specific item/node in this treeviewer.

To build the treeviewer, I did this:

```
viewer = new TreeViewer(composite);
viewer.getTree().setLayoutData(gridData);
viewer.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
viewer.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
viewer.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(folderName.getText()));
viewer.expandAll();
```

Until here, everything is ok, but now, I don't know how to use listeners to do something when I select a specific item in my tree. Any idea? Thanks.

Edit: I got it!

```
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(
            new ISelectionChangedListener(){
                public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
                    if(event.getSelection() instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
                        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();            
                        Object o = selection.getFirstElement();    

                        if (o instanceof IFile){

                            IFile file = (IFile)o;

                        }else {
                            //what ?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an **excellent first step** but there is even a better way which is more in the **heart and soul of Eclipse**.

Your code is listening to local changes but **you want to make your code extendable** so that **other plugins** in Eclipse are also notified when someone selects something in your viewer.

### Eclipse 4 API

For this to happen you inject ESelectionService into your part and then forward the selection to the workbench by using the listener you already provided.

```
@Inject
private ESelectionService selectionService;

viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
  IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
  // set the selection to the service
  selectionService.setSelection(
      selection.size() == 1 ? selection.getFirstElement() : selection.toArray());
```

Then, to catch your own selection:

```
@Inject
void setSelection(@Optional @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) IFile pFile) {
  if (pFile == null) {
    //what ?
  } else {
    // magic!
  }
}
```

### Eclipse 3 API

For this to happen you have to register your viewer with the selection framework. Add this in the createPartControl method of the part where you have added your viewer:

```
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

Then, to catch your own selection:

```
    getSite().getPage().addPostSelectionListener(this); // Implement ISelectionListener
```

References: https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Selection